# What kinds of rear wheel hubs are compatible with my MTB?

Tags: mountain-bike, replacement, freehub, 12-speed

I am looking at a rear wheel replacement. I have a Scott Scale 980 with a standard wheel on the rear. Will I need a longer freehub to interface with the wide 12 speed cassette? Or are there general standard wheels that are compatible?

Comment: Not all 980s are Shimano, my 2017 is SRAM NX with a SRAM XD (or compatible) freehub. Gears are SRAM NX. (Sorry can't post in comments as at work).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 3 standards of hub interfaces in modern MTBs.
Which one you need is determined by the cassette you want to use:

**Shimano HG:** (sometimes called Shimano Standard or 11-speed hub) fits Shimano/SRAM cassettes up to 11-speed and SRAM SX/NX Eagle 12-speed cassettes

**Shimano Micro Spline:** All Shimano 12-speed cassettes

**SRAM XD:** SRAM GX/X01/XX1/X0/XX Eagle 12-speed cassettes

Answer (score 2):

[The Scott Scale 980](https://mtbdatabase.com/bikes/2021/scott/scale/2021-scott-scale-980/) comes stock with a rear hub that is a 5mm QR (Quick Release skewer) with an over-lock-nut (OLD) of 142mm. This is a NON-boost hub (boost is 148mm OLD). The freehub body is a Shimano Microspline which is compatible with the Shimano Deore M6100 12 speed drivetrain.

Thus, when you shop for a rear wheel replacement (the wheels are 29ers or 622 in ETRTO), you'll require the hub to be the 142mm OLD with QR skewer and spec'd with a Microspline freehub body to fit the current Shimano 12 speed cassette.

Comment: it looks like it is a boost in fact (with quick release)

Comment: @Renaud I'm not sure why the manufacturers (the marketing departments, certainly) call a 141mm OLD hub with a 10mm hollow axle that takes a 5mm skewer, "boost." Perhaps the term started and stuck when the MTB O.L.D. went from 135 to 141/142.  Nothing but the O.L.D. grew with those hubs as they kept the same spoke flange distance as the 135mm OLD hubs.  To me, a boost hub has a thru axle with a 148mm OLD and the whole thing is +6mm wider between the spoke flanges. A real  boost. Big point is OP cannot  fit a boost 148 hub nor a thru axle on the bike in question.

Comment: Marketing also has the ability to give new meaning to names, this hub is called 5x141 Boost by Shimano. Until I saw this question, I also linked Boost to 12x148 TA. But it turns out now that boost is 141mm OLD, so 5x141 is the QR equivalent to 12x148TA (as 5x135 matches 12x142TA). Relative to the center plane of the bike, using a non-boost won't match, wrong width, brake position and chainline (the crankset must be boost too). [drawing](https://www.sumcchain.com/cdn/shop/products/O1CN0160Gu8S2FKOHiSs5Bw__3885718861-0-cib_e5b192aa-e76a-4146-b54b-f61857c8a087.jpg?v=1663755338&width=990).